# Number of distinct perfect matching in a d-regular graph.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I have a claim that every **d-regular bipartite graph** has at least **d!** distinct perfect matchings. Is this claim is true? if yes then can somebody tell me the proof?
Actually there is a problem that ask to show that any r X n latin rectangle can be extended to a n X n latin square and there are at least (n-r)! ways to do it. Now this problem can be easily reduced to a (n-r) regular bipartite graph(V=X U Y) where X = [n] and Y = set of Bj where Bj is the set of number that are not present in column j. You can also see this math.toronto.edu/gscott/MAT332notes_latinsquares.pdf

Comment: Please expand on your post.  Since you claim the proposition, why do you support it?  Please show us your work that led to "your" claim.  Of course, you can also cite the source of the claim, and where you found it.

Comment: Actually there is a problem that ask to show that any r X n latin rectangle can be extended to a n X n latin square and there are at least (n-r)! ways to do it. Now this problem can be easily reduced to a (n-r) regular bipartite graph(V=X U Y) where X = [n] and Y = set of Bj where Bj is the set of number that are not present in column j. You can also see this http://www.math.toronto.edu/gscott/MAT332notes_latinsquares.pdf

Comment: @SoumyajitPyne: Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4347152/edit) that into the question.